# Video and game lags after rooting S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, performance

I recently rooted my phone, and am now using Paranoid and I love it. However, whenever I play videos and games it lags really noticeably. This never happened before I rooted my phone. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 and have tried using Seeder with no luck. Can I fix this poor performance?

Comment: Goto the forum site for your ROM. See if they have a fix or a workaround. It might be a performance settings problem (ie. wrong processor/governor setting or other). But you'll have read to see what other Paranoid users say.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug in the custom ROM you've installed. You should report it to the developer of the ROM, and either wait for it to be fixed in an update, or use a different ROM.